# How to change for loops into while loops in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am still sort of new to python, I can do anything with a while loop and I am still having trouble comprehending that. 
`for i in range(len(s)):`
`for x in a: <- where a is an empty set`

Comment: please use code block when writing code in your question. It's also not clear what u are asking here.

Answer (score 2):

To get items out of a `set` without a `for` loop, you can use an iterator. This is probably what your prof. is referring to. Example:

```
i = iter(s)
while True:
    try:
        next(i)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Note that you can call `next(i, default)` to avoid the exception at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in a `while` loop but sometimes it can be awkward. The thing about a `for` loop is that it consumes a sequence.

For your first example, the loop is pretty straight forward because all we really wanted was in index in `s`

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(i)

i = 0
while i < len(s):
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Your second example is more problematic because you can't index sets. Likely, the best way to handle it is to convert the set to a list and index that. Or you could mimic `for` by creating your own iterator for the set and handling the end-of-iteration exception yourself.

```
a = set()
for x in a:
    print(x)

# this would be illegal because you can't index the set
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    print(a[i]) # ERROR
    i += 1

# so we make a list
i = 0
_a = list(a)
while i < len(_a):
    print(_a[i])
    i += 1

# or use an iterator for the set
a_iter = iter(a)
while True:
    try:
        print(next(a_iter))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

In some languages like C, `while` is just an abreviated form of `for`...

```
while(x < 5)) {...}
for(;x < 5;) {...}
```

but as you can see, such is not the case with python.